# ulimit broke my server

Tags: memory, virtual-memory, xen, ulimit

I ran "ulimit -v 75" to get SBCL working, and now nothing will run on my server.

```
$ sbcl
Killed
$ vi
Killed
$ man ulimit
Killed
$ ulimit -v 256
-bash: ulimit: virtual memory: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

How can I reset the ulimit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge `ulimit` in Bash and other shells is "local" to the shell instance (more generally to the process and children). You can lower it but not raise it again on your own. But you can likely log in on another terminal and **get another shell instance without that limit**.

Comment: mcandre:  Try this one first -- it's a better answer.  =)

Comment: HUGE sigh of relief.

Comment: @mcandre: I guess we all had that at one point or another :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "exec" command:  exec ulimit -v 256

If that doesn't work, this might get you rebooting at least:  exec reboot